# Selenium Implementing Try Except with writing to JSON

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on a web scraper and trying to build in some exceptions so when the element doesn't exist it just skips on to the next element.

I am scraping more than 10 elements and not sure the best way to find the exception and go to the next element with all of them, I understand I can do an IF statement or a Try/Except.

I have tried to implement the Try/Except concept (as below) but I think I've used it incorrectly as 1. I'm, missing some results in printing (the ones that are not an exception), 2. It's writing and printing incorrect data to JSON, where the result doesn't exist - It seems to be using the data from the last row (I think).

How do I make an exception to move to scrape the next element if the data doesn't exist, for all the elements I am scraping?

The code I am working with is as below (Simplified):

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time
import json
import csv

def writeToJSONFile(path, fileName, data):
    filePathNameWExt = './' + path + '/' + fileName + '.json'
    with open(filePathNameWExt, 'a') as fp:
        json.dump(data, fp, ensure_ascii=False)

urls = ['https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Restaurant_Review-g186338-d8122594-Reviews-Humble_Grape_Battersea-London_England.html','https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Restaurant_Review-g186338-d5561842-Reviews-Gastronhome-London_England.html']


browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/Users/path/Downloads/geckodriver")

data = []
for url in urls:

    browser.get(url)
    page = browser.find_element_by_class_name('non_hotels_like')
    title = page.find_element_by_class_name('heading_title').text
    street_address = page.find_element_by_class_name('street-address').text

    try:
        day1 = page.find_element_by_xpath("//DIV[@class='hours content']//SPAN[@class='day'][text()='Monday']").text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass
    #day1_hours = page.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='hours content']//div[2]//span[2]//div[1]").text

        print(title)
        print(street_address)
        print(day1)
        #print(day1_hours)

    data.append({'title': title, 'street_address': street_address, 'day1': day1})

filename = 'properties'

writeToJSONFile('./', filename, data)

browser.quit()
```

UPDATE as John advised I have put a catch in - although now getting an invalid syntax error!:

```
try:
    day1 = page.find_element_by_xpath("//DIV[@class='hours content']//SPAN[@class='day'][text()='Monday']").text
except NoSuchElementException:
        catch NoSuchElementException:
        day1 = 'Element not found'
```

Comment: Question 1. Which data might be absent? `page`, `title`, `street_address ` or just `day1`? Question 2. Why do you want to locate element by text `"Monday"` to scrape text `"Monday"`?

Comment: title, street_address  and day1 may all be absent. I am also finding the hours so need the time and day to match up... If that makes sense... Unless you know of a better way! Thanks!

Comment: If title, street address, and other elements can all be missing, then you probably want to wrap each `find_element...` call in a try/catch block to assign a default value if it's not found.

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes That's what I'm looking to do! Just struggling to make it work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From your code layout, it seems possible that you could find the `page`, `title` and `street_address` elements, but not the `day1` element.  If that happens, how do you want to handle it?

If you want to skip that url entirely, move the `print()` and `data.append(...)` statements inside the `try:` block.

If you want to use some default value for `day1`, assign it in the `catch` block:

```
catch NoSuchElementException:
    day1 = 'Element not found'
```

Comment: I want to still get that URL just not the element that doesn't exist! Thanks!

Comment: Would you be able to advise me how to implement this in the code? I have made an attempt, to no avail! Thanks!

Comment: Put `day1 = 'Element not found'` in place of the `pass` statement.

Comment: Ok, just tired that getting and invalid syntax error!

Comment: Update your question to include the new code.  We can't help if we don't know exactly what the code is.

Comment: Whoops, I was using the term "catch" generically, but python uses "except".  Take out the `catch` line.  Also, you probably want to unindent the `print()` statements, as they're at the same indent level as the `except` block.